# Redshift queries do not finish after dropping and recreating tables

Tags: amazon-redshift

I have a few tables in a redshift cluster. When I drop say table `A` and recreate the table with the records in it using `CREATE` and the `COPY` command, any query on table `A` never finishes execution (even a simple `select * from A;`). I need to reboot the cluster and execute the query again for it to finish, be it any sort of query. What's the solution here ?

Comment: To be clear the DROP, CREATE, and COPY all complete successfully, right?  Could be a lot of things but my initial thought is locks.  Are you executing these through a single connection or multiple?  Is the subsequent SELECT run on a different connection?  Did you COMMIT the results of the DROP, CREATE, and COPY?  The SELECT could be waiting to get a shared-read lock on the table but cannot until the previous statements commit.

Comment: Yes the DROP statement finishes. When I recreate the table using CREATE and COPY commands, ANY query on the table NEVER finishes. I am using DataGrip. How do I commit ? @BillWeiner

Comment: I've never used DataGrip so my comments will be Redshift focused.  To commit the results of a transaction you just say "COMMIT;".  This publishes the results for all to see and will release any locks.  If you can make an interactive connection to Redshift you can look at the locks that are in flight when things don't finish. This script may help https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-redshift-utils/blob/master/src/AdminViews/v_check_transaction_locks.sql

Comment: After a chat with AWS folks I got to know that there has to be a delay after every table is created so redshift can ingest it. Putting a time.sleep(10) fixed the issue. Thanks !